# Executing OPENQUERY Syntax with DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T> in Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

We are planning to upgrade from EF4.2 to 6 and are experiencing issues with functionality that worked in 4.2.

```
SELECT emp_no_alpha as EmployeeNumber, code_user_1 as Code1, emp_name as EmployeeName FROM OPENQUERY(EMS02, 'select emp_no_alpha, code_user_1, emp_name from dce_mms where emp_no_alpha =''   100393'' ')
```

We use the above statement in combination with dbContext.Database.SqlQuery($sql-stmt) to retrieve entities.  This works fine against this model in 4.2:

```
public abstract class Model_XX_EMS_DCEMMS
    {
        //LEN=9, RIGHT PAD
        [Column("EMP_NO_ALPHA", Order = 0), Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

        //LEN=5, RIGHT PAD
        [Column("CODE_USER_1")]
        public string Code1 { get; set; }

        [Column("EMP_NAME")]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    }
```

However in 6.0, SQL profiler attempts to actually create a Model_XX_EMS_DCEMMS table within the default catalog and never executes the select statement, therefore returning null.

This is what happens in 6.0:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND (t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + t.TABLE_NAME IN ('dbo.Model_XX_EMS_DCEMMS')
        OR t.TABLE_NAME = 'EdmMetadata')
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Model_XX_EMS_DCEMMS] (
    [EMP_NO_ALPHA] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [CODE_USER_1] [nvarchar](max),
    [EMP_NAME] [nvarchar](max),
    [Discriminator] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Model_XX_EMS_DCEMMS] PRIMARY KEY ([EMP_NO_ALPHA])
)
```

Is there a new DbContext configuration or some attributes that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework is creating a table with a discriminator column to support [Table Per Hierarchy  inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)

But with OPENQUERY you don't want that table. To stop EF creating a table like that for the abstract class you will need [Table Per Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx) or [Table Per Concrete Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx)

I don't know <strike>much</strike> anything about OPENQUERY. Could you create a View that EF could use to support the abstract class in TPT? Then add table attributes to the tables that inherit this class.

As for why it worked before, this quote from the TPC page makes me think things changed in EF or you lost some manual XML rewrites.

> Entity Data Model Designer in VS2010 doesn't support TPC (even though the EF runtime does). That basically means if you are following EF's Database-First or Model-First approaches then configuring TPC requires manually writing XML in the EDMX file which is not considered to be a fun practice. Well, no more.

Comment: Thank You for the explanation.  As suggested in a MSDN cross-post I have removed the DbSet<> from my DbContext and all works now.  I would love to see OPENQUERY support in EF.